# Get rid of Qt's dotted outline on QListView items

Tags: qt, pyqt4, qtstylesheets

I'm trying to remove the dotted border on the text in this `QListView::item` using stylesheets:

[image: QListView with dotted outline shown on selected item]

I've tried variations of `border: 0` and `show-decoration-selected: 0` on `QListView`, `QListView::item` and `QListView::item::text` to no effect.

I'm using PyQt, but I believe the stylesheet rules are the same as in the C++ libraries.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After some more testing, I found that the following stylesheet works:

```
QListView {
    outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Setting `outline: 0;` in the stylesheet doesn't work for me (anymore?).
The only solution I could find was to set the ListView's FocusPolicy to `Qt::NoFocus`, which comes with obvious drawbacks.

Comment: One possible reason for `outline: 0` not working in a `QListWidget` is if you set it on the `QListWidget::item` instead of the `QListWidget` itself. Not sure if this also holds for the `QListView` case.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the border to none seems to have done the trick for me.

```
QListView::item { 
    border: none;
}
```