# Style QtComboBox, QListViewItem - Set text padding

Tags: css, qt

Info: Qt 4.8, Qt Designer

I'm struggling to set the padding of the text items on a combobox drop down. My understanding is the whole thing is the QComboBox widget, and the drop down part is a QListView. But I can't work out what css selector to use to change the style of the text items in the drop down list.

I want the hover item's background color to extend all the way left, instead of leaving a 5px margin. The text itself is lined up fine, just that white gap on the left is bugging me.

Also I would be great if I could remove the dotted border around the highlighted item.

[image]

I guess I'm just not using the correct item selector. I've tried QListView::item, and QListViewItem. Here is my CSS applied to the combobox.

```
QComboBox{
border:                 none;
background-color:   rgb(87, 96, 134);
color:                      rgb(255, 255, 255);
font-weight:            bold;
padding:                    5px 

}

QComboBox::drop-down{
    border:                 none;
    background-color:   rgb(87, 96, 134);
    color:                      rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-weight:            bold;
    padding:                    0px;
}

QComboBox::down-arrow{
    image:                      url(:/icons/combobox_down_arrow.png);
    padding-right:          5px;
}

QListView{
    border:                 none;
    color:                      rgb(87, 96, 134);
    background-color:   rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-weight:            bold;
    selection-background-color: rgb(47, 175, 178);
    show-decoration-selected: 1;
    margin-left:                -10px;
    padding-left    :           15px;
}

QListView::item:hover{

    background-color:   rgb(47, 175, 178);
    border:                 none;
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Comment: @alirezasafian Does jsfiddle work with Qt?

Comment: I think It does not.

Comment: a fiddle/snippet definitely would be good to help you out.

Comment: This is in QtDesigner. You pop in a QComboBox and apply the stylesheet code included above. There is no snippet or fiddle I can do besides.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15830383

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to remove the dotter border using only CSS by setting undocumented property `outline`:

```
QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    outline: none;
}
```

`QListView` also can be used in this selector. `QAbstractItemView` is used in this example, since it is a base class of `QListView`. Note that this property is set not per item but for the external container of items.

There are other ways to remove the dotted border using coding, for example [QT - CSS: decoration on focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280056/qt-css-decoration-on-focus)

---

It looks that it is needed to change the code to have better flexibility with padding. `QComboBox` uses its own private implementation of `QAbstractItemDelegate` based on `QItemDelegate`. However, other controls use `QStyledItemDelegate`
([`QStyledItemDelegate` vs. `QItemDelegate`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#qstyleditemdelegate-vs-qitemdelegate)). That is why CSS selectors for items (`QListView::item`) does not have an effect on `QComboBox` items.

There is the following comment with explanation in the source code:

> Note that this class is intentionally not using `QStyledItemDelegate`
>   Vista does not use the new theme for combo boxes and there might be
>   other side effects from using the new class

If the above comment is not a problem, it is possible to set `QStyledItemDelegate` to `QComboBox` objects:

```
QComboBox *combobox = new QComboBox;
combobox->setItemDelegate(new QStyledItemDelegate(combobox));
```

Now, the property `selection-background-color` is not needed anymore. It is possible to customize `::item`:

```
QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item {
    border: none;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item:selected {
    background: rgb(47, 175, 178);
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Note that to set padding it is also needed to provide, for example, at least border or background property together with padding. Otherwise the padding property is not taken into account.

The selector `::item:selected` is used instead of `:hover`, since items can be also selected by keyboard.

---

Although it is documented that it is possible to set custom *view* for `QComboBox` it is not so simple. `QComboBox` can also have separator items. The above solution works fine if there are no separator items in `QComboBox`. To handle separators the item delegate should also know about them.

It is possible to subclass `QStyledItemDelegate` and copy required functions from Qt private implementation of `QComboBoxDelegate`. That solution is not very nice. It may be **non-portable with new Qt versions**. The implementation of `QComboBoxDelegate` in Qt5 is not compatible with Qt4. However, Qt5 can work with Qt4 implementation, so this class can be taken from Qt4. The `QItemDelegate` base class is replaced by `QStyledItemDelegate`:

```
class ComboBoxDelegateStyled : public QStyledItemDelegate
{ 
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ComboBoxDelegateStyled(QObject *parent, QComboBox *cmb) :
        QStyledItemDelegate(parent), mCombo(cmb) {}

    static bool isSeparator(const QModelIndex &index) {
        return index.data(Qt::AccessibleDescriptionRole).toString() == QLatin1String("separator");
    }

protected:
    void paint(QPainter *painter,
               const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
               const QModelIndex &index) const {
        if (isSeparator(index)) {
            QRect rect = option.rect;
            if (const QStyleOptionViewItemV3 *v3 = qstyleoption_cast<const QStyleOptionViewItemV3*>(&option))
                if (const QAbstractItemView *view = qobject_cast<const QAbstractItemView*>(v3->widget))
                    rect.setWidth(view->viewport()->width());
            QStyleOption opt;
            opt.rect = rect;
            mCombo->style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_IndicatorToolBarSeparator, &opt, painter, mCombo);
        } else {
            QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
        }
    }

    QSize sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                   const QModelIndex &index) const {
        if (isSeparator(index)) {
            int pm = mCombo->style()->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_DefaultFrameWidth, 0, mCombo);
            return QSize(pm, pm);
        }
        return QStyledItemDelegate::sizeHint(option, index);
    }
private:
    QComboBox *mCombo;
};
```

It makes sense to subclass `QComboBox` to use `ComboBoxDelegateStyled`:

```
class ComboBoxStyled : public QComboBox
{
public:
    explicit ComboBoxStyled(QWidget *parent = 0) : QComboBox(parent) {
        setItemDelegate(new ComboBoxDelegateStyled(this, this));
    }
};
```

Now the class `ComboBoxStyled` can be used instead of `QComboBox`. It supports combo box separator drawing and also it supports CSS for `::item`.

Similar solution for customizing `QComboBox` separator: [how to add stylesheet for separator in QCombobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828160/how-to-add-stylesheet-for-separator-in-qcombobox)

---

**PyQt**

The above behavior is valid for PyQt. It is possible to remove dotted border using `outline` and to set styled item delegate to customize CSS `::item`:

```
styledComboBox = QtGui.QComboBox()
delegate = QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate()
styledComboBox.setItemDelegate(delegate)
```

In such case the combo box separator is displayed as a regular item without text.
It is also possible to create custom delegate to handle separators.

Comment: My word. I was rather hoping for a "No silly, use this css bit instead". I will have a run through this tomorrow morning and see what I can get working. I am working with PyQt so I am not sure how much I can recode things. I'll look at it again tomorrow. Thank you for such an informed and detailed answer though.

Comment: @Oliver For PyQt everything is the same. I updated the answer. It looks that for customizing separators it is still needed to write custom delegate. I hate such tweaks in projects, but it is the solution. If you do not care about combo box separator it is enough to set `QStyledItemDelegate` (it makes sense to use custom subclass of `QComboBox` to create many such combo boxes).